# socket io how to emit event to buddies?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, io

Hi I'm making a chat with node js and I have a question. The chat is global, without rooms but users can only see and write to users in their buddy list. So when they connect to the server, they'll send also the user id and the buddy list as array. In the server I have a global variable with online users. Now, which is the best way to emit the event to users in the buddy list?

This  is my current code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var confdb = require('./lib/config-db.js');
var conf = require('./lib/config.js');
var db = require('./lib/chat-db');
var whitelist = [];
var secret_st = '';
var chrlimit = '';
var socketio_jwt = require('socketio-jwt');
var uidlist = {};
var id = {};
var mongodburl = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

// initialize db ===============================================================

mongoose.connect(mongodburl); // connect to our database
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// set up our express application

confdb.findOne({'check': '1'}).exec(function(err, docs){
    if (docs) {
        whitelist = docs.origin;
        secret_st = docs.spku;
        chrlimit = docs.chrlimit;
        if (docs.badwld) {
            badwl = JSON.parse(docs.badwld);
        }
    } else {
        conf.saveconfig();
    }
    startall();
});

function startall() {
    var corsOptions = {
      origin: function(origin, callback){
        var originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
        callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
      }
    };

    app.use(cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next) {
        next();
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    // launch ======================================================================
    var server = app.listen(port);
    var io = socketio.listen(server);

    //Routes ======================================================

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end();
    });

    var nspm = io.of('/member');
    nspm.use(socketio_jwt.authorize({
        secret: secret_st,
        handshake: true
    }));
    nspm.on('connection', function(socket) {
        db.c_oneusr(socket.decoded_token, function(err, docs){
            nspm.to(socket.id).emit('ckusr', 'ok');
            initializeConnection(socket, 0);
        });
    });

    function initializeConnection(socket, lstshout){
        showActiveUsers(socket, lstshout);
    }

    function showActiveUsers(socket, lstshout){
        socket.uid = socket.decoded_token.uid;
        uidlist[socket.uid] = 1;
        if (!id[socket.uid]) {
            id[socket.uid] = {};
        }
        if (!msgtime[socket.uid]) {
            msgtime[socket.uid] = [];
        }
        msgtime[socket.uid]['lpmsgt'] = lstshout;
        id[socket.uid][socket.id] = 1;
        socket.emit('login', {
            uidlist: uidlist
        });
        // I need to change this and emit it only to buddies
        socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
            uidlist: uidlist,
            uid: socket.uid
        });
        data = [];
        data["uid"] = socket.decoded_token.uid;
        data["id"] = socket.id;
        data["buddies"] = socket.decoded_token.buddies;
        db.updpml(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: "they'll send also the user id and the buddy list as array", shouldn't the buddy list be kept on the server? Generally the question is far too broad, you need to show code, in particular where your online users are stored, where the "buddy list" comes into play and how the messaging currently works.

Comment: The problem is not the messaging now, I only need to emit the action of login to the other users. I don't keep the buddy list in the chat server because I use the main software buddy list system. And the online users variable is global and it is an array with ids of online users.

Comment: This is my code:
https://pastebin.com/bRejejUe

Comment: before you continue: please put the code in the question using the [edit] link, not into a comment.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I updated the first post.